# Perpetual Loading

Tags: asp.net-mvc, identityserver3

I have an identity server setup using identityserver3 and whenever I go to connect to my site after logging it, it gets caught in what looks like a perpetual redirect.

I have logging turned on and I noticed that some lines related to CSP are in there, which makes me think this is the problem, but I don't have a clue as to how to fix it.

> 2016-01-13 12:43:17.738 -05:00 [Information] rendering login page
>
> 2016-01-13 12:43:18.203 -05:00 [Information] CSP Report endpoint requested
>
> 2016-01-13 12:43:18.208 -05:00 [Information] CSP Report data: "{\"csp-report\":{\"blocked-uri\":\"self\",\"document-uri\":\"http://example.com.com:44200/core/login?signin=someGuid\",\"line-number\":1,\"original-policy\":\"default-src http://example.com:44200; script-src http://example.com:44200; style-src http://example.com:44200 'unsafe-inline'; img-src *; report-uri http://example.com:44200/core/csp/report\",\"referrer\":\"\",\"script-sample\":\"try {  for(var lastpass_iter=0; lastpass...\",\"source-file\":\"http://example.com:44200/core/login?signin=someGuid\",\"violated-directive\":\"script-src http://example.com:44200\"}}"
>
> 2016-01-13 12:43:18.208 -05:00 [Information] CSP Report data: "{\"csp-report\":{\"blocked-uri\":\"self\",\"document-uri\":\"http://example.com:44200/core/login?signin=someGuid\",\"original-policy\":\"default-src http://example.com:44200; script-src http://example.com:44200; style-src http://example.com:44200 'unsafe-inline'; img-src *; report-uri http://example.com:44200/core/csp/report\",\"referrer\":\"\",\"script-sample\":\"onerror attribute on IMG element\",\"source-file\":\"http://example.com:44200/core/login?signin=someGuid\",\"violated-directive\":\"script-src http://example.com:44200\"}}"
>
> 2016-01-13 12:43:18.223 -05:00 [Information] CSP Report data: "{\"csp-report\":{\"blocked-uri\":\"data:image/png;base64,someText\",\"document-uri\":\"http://example.com:44200/core/login?signin=someGuid\",\"original-policy\":\"default-src http://example.com:44200; script-src http://example.com:44200; style-src http://example.com:44200 'unsafe-inline'; img-src *; report-uri http://example.com:44200/core/csp/report\",\"referrer\":\"\",\"violated-directive\":\"img-src *\"}}"
>
> 2016-01-13 12:43:18.226 -05:00 [Information] Rendering 204

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify CSP options using the `CSPOptions` property of your `IdentityServerOptions`. Find documentation here: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/advanced/csp.html

If you want to test if CSP is your issue, you can try disabling it completely using these options.

Looking at the logs you may need to add the value `'self'` to the `ScriptSrc`.